# Update stuck due to low space

Tags: update

My Win10 phone was low in storage but it automatically started updating to new build/version. As a result when almost 600 MB download was left the update failed. Now I can neither update completely nor can I remove the incomplete downloaded system files. How can I recover my space by deleting or completing the incomplete update?
Thanks!

Comment: What phone do you have? Maybe you can add an SD card and move some apps over to free up some space?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem long ago.

What I did was removing a lot of applications, redo the update (this time successfully) and reinstall the applications again.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced same issue. 
-> Try to uninstall apps from mobile memory. 
-> Temporarily disconnect from your outlook mail.
-> If you have whatsapp, take backup to SD card and uninstall which will give some free space.